# Open the same webpage, but with another content

Tags: grails

Im developing a webapp that is feeded via a server. Its index presents some shops deals, having all of these deals ann id. In the .gsp, i have this code:

```
<div id="content">
<g:each in='${promos}' var='promo'>
<div id="up_box"></div>
<div class="deal_container">
    <div class="images_container"><img src="${createLink(action:'showImage',controller:'image',id:promo.fotoPrincipal.id)}" width="120" height="105" />

    </div>

    <g:link controller='promotion' action='openPromo' params="[promoid:promo.id]">

   <div class="oferta">${promo.name}</div>
   </g:link>
    <g:link controller='promotion' action='openPromo' params="[promoid:promo.id]">
    <div class="flecha">
     </div>
    </g:link>


</div>
```

That means, when I click in one of the links, it will open an url like this:

```
app/promotion/openPromo/3
```

In case the deal with the id "3" is clicked. I have a "general" deal details page. I want that page to load always, and fulfill its details dinamically, depending the deal the user clicked. How can I do that?

I don't know if I have been clear in my explanation, if i haven't please ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both links will be handled by the `openPromo` action in the `PromotionController` and will be passed the `id` of the promo as `promoid`.

You can then load the appropriate promo along with any other related offers you want the user to see and give these to the view. Eg:

```
class PromotionController {

  def openPromo() {
    Promo promo = Promo.get(params.promoid)

    // Load any other relevant data or offers

   render (view:'openPromo', model:[promo:promo, <any other model data here>]
  }
}
```

You can then use the model data in your `gsp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it adding that general info to a Template and then render it from the Controller like this

```
// render a template to the response for the specified model
def theShining = new Book(title: 'The Shining', author: 'Stephen King')
render(template: "book", model: [book: theShining])
```

You´ve got more info about the render in this link from the Grails documentation.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

It´s easy to do it, you can add a createLink like the first ones whith calls to an action who will render that template.

Hope it helps ;) and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, after asking my workmate:

```
def openPromo() {
    Promotion promo = Promotion.get(params.promoid)
    [promo:promo]
}
```

Almost what you said David, but without rendering, if I name `openPromo` my gsp.

Thank you!

Comment: Great! the `[promo:promo]` is short hand for `render(view:'openPromo', model:[promo:promo])` in the case where the `gsp` is the same name as the controller.